# Can't cast from Dictionary value to Array

Tags: ios, swift

No idea why this won't work. The value of this dictionary is a key, yet whenever I try to cast to an array, I get a multitude of errors. Here's what I've tried, with the error I get following each example (in all examples, `parameters` is type `[String : Any]`:

```
let paramsArray = parameters["inputVO"] as AnyObject
if let array = paramsArray as? Array {

}
```

Error: `Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred in cast to 'Array<_>'`

```
if let array = parameters["inputVO"] as? Array {

}
```

Error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`

I'm not sure what else to do to cast the result to an array? I'm sure I've done this before, I have no idea why this is failing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's the output when I print out `params`. As expected, it is populated with an `Array` of `Dictionary`'s.

```
Optional([["stmtDate": cmd, "transId": identifier, "isSupplementDataAvailable": true]])
```

Comment: What's it an array of?

Comment: I'm expecting an array of `[String : Any]` (I know it's a weird structure.... Such are the joys of conforming to an API that my team didn't have a say in designing)

Comment: Can you print `parameters["inputVO"]` and paste the result into the question to show what the app thinks is in there?

Comment: What is the exact type of `parameters`? You have to share more of the code surrounding your example for us to help you.

Comment: The type is `[String : Any]`. A`Dictionary` with `String` keys and `Any` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either it's an array

```
if let array = parameters["inputVO"] as? [[String:Any]] { ... }
```

or a dictionary

```
if let dictionary = parameters["inputVO"] as? [String:Any] { ... }
```

Both types are generics and need specific type information

- `[[String:Any]]` is the short form of `Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>`
- `[String:Any]` is the short form of `Dictionary<String,Any>`

Comment: You are 100% correctn `let paramsArray = params["inputVO"] as [[String : Any]]` worked beautifully. I guess intuitively thinking about it, that makes sense, as Swift needs to know what type of element the array is holding.