# Can't traverse array element of Dictionary of <String: Any>

Tags: swift

Trying to figure out why this throws an error ("Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout Dictionary') at the for loop below in Xcode 8.1:

```
var fooDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
fooDict["test"] = "I'm a string"
fooDict["numberTest"] = "12345"
fooDict["arrayTest"] = [1,3,4,"five"]

for item in (fooDict["arrayTest"] as! Array)
{
print(item)

}
```

Comment: On which line does this occur?

Comment: Related: [Can't cast from Dictionary value to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39799149/2976878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indicate that the array is of type Any. Like this:

```
for item in (fooDict["arrayTest"] as! Array<Any>)
{
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error here is confusing and pointing you in the wrong direction. You can't have just `Array` in Swift. It has to be an array of something specific. In this case, you mean an array of `Any`, so you have to say so:

```
for item in (fooDict["arrayTest"] as! [Any])
```